# Use joint pdf to answer questions about random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

Hi, can I get some help on this I already did this but I need to collaborate my work to see if Im on the right track: my answers to the questions are 
a) Prob{ total water level < 3 } = 0.4037
b) EA = 0.6673
c) xlow = 0.0526 xhi = 1.9474

Comment: It is not collabrate, but corroborate.

Comment: well sorry I try with my english

Comment: Please show some of your work...

Comment: @peter,  I have worked out the problem for you and you are almost right on all parts except the last for which I differ from your answer.  Take a look at it and see if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

I have given the solution in hand-written form.  Let me know if it is legible.  See if you approached the problem differently than mine.  This is my best effort.

[image]
[image]